# NoCopy function made in JavaScript is not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, function, firefox

I am trying to make my web pages DO-NOT-COPY protected.. I got the following code.. it works with chrome & IE but not with firefox..

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    function NoCopy(e)
    {
        return false
    }
    function ReActivate()
    {
        return true
    }

    document.onselectstart = new Function ("return false")

    if(document.sidebar)
    {
        document.onmousedown = NoCopy
        document.onclick = ReActivate
    }</script>
```

Can anyone help me with this??

Thanks in advance

Comment: typo in `document` (wriiten as `zocument`)

Comment: Ctrl + U / View source / Disabled JavaScript / Curl / .... There are plenty of methods to copy the contents. Do not try to implement "anti-copy" by blocking certain features. Instead, add a visible copyright/license note (at the footer?).

Comment: gopi, that's spelling error.. problem still exists

Comment: Rob, that's true.. still we need the restriction like you can see in many other sites also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you want to prevent copy by selecting text, the above method is **not** good. Instead add a `copyright notice/license` or I recommend that you **CSS**:

```
body {
   -webkit-touch-callout: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not restrict the user copying the text by using Javascript. If the content is send from your server then user can do anything with that.

User can check your website on a website that deosn't support Javascript or user can use CURL functions in php and read the content. There are many options.. So protect your content by using the copyright.